# Building class to dezerialize from this? can't get it to work

Tags: c#, xml

Hello i'm trying to build class to dezerilize it to an object list.

heres the link to the document.
https://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/top/technology.xml

Error message i get when im trying.
 'There is an error in XML document'

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried

Comment: Which code lead to error you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an encoding issue with your code.  The following works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program1
    {
        const string URL = "https://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/top/technology.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            List<Item> items = doc.Descendants("item").Select(x => new Item()
            {
                title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                link = (string)x.Element("link"),
                description = (string)x.Element("description"),
                _pubDate = (string)x.Element("pubDate"),
                guid = (string)x.Element("guid")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public DateTime pubDate { get; set; }
        public string _pubDate {
            get
            { return pubDate.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss EDT"); }
            set { 
                string[] splitDate = value.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                pubDate = DateTime.ParseExact(splitDate[1].Trim(), "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss EDT", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
        public string guid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping! I was trying with <channel> as a class and item as list<item> with the elements from an item class!